# SQL getting record for maximum value: why not use "ORDER BY"?

Tags: sql, max, sql-order-by

I know that the "select record corresponding to the maximum value for a field" has been exhaustively answered, but I was wondering why nobody suggested using an ORDER BY clause to get the right row.

For example, I have this table:

```
| other_field | target_field |
| 1           | 15           |
| 2           | 25           |
| 3           | 20           |
```

and I want to find the `other_field` value corresponding to the maximum `target_field` (e.g. in this case, I want to find 2).

Many people suggested using GROUP and JOIN, however my first idea was to use:

```
SELECT other_field FROM table ORDER by target_field DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is there anything wrong with this? The only problem I can think of is that maybe ordering takes longer then just find the maximum (although on the other hand the JOIN might also take a while).

Thanks!

EDIT: sorry guys for the late replies, I'm new here and I was expecting to get some e-mails for notifications :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It actually has to sort every record before it can return any data. It's highly inefficient. It will return what you want, but not in the best possible way. Aggregate functions tend to do it much better, and much quicker.

With your current query, once you reached a much higher data load, it would take ages to process and materialize. (With smaller data sets, you should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need single value from one or more than one tables then you have to go for Max and GroupBy
2. if you are only one table and requires multiple columns then it is ok to use Order By Desc.
3. if you again need a single value from single table then MAX is preferred here too.

I hope you got my points

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following query :

```
select top 1 other_field from tester order by target_field desc;
```

It works well in Sybase. Not sure of other databases.

Comment: I've checked on Google, and this looks the same as "order by ... limit ...", but not supported on MySQL (but you're right, I never specified I was referring to MySQL).